# Why the cellForRowAt method is not getting called

Tags: uitableview, tableview

-> I have taken a class which is a child of NSObject in that class I have created the tableView object.

-> The numberOfRowsInSection & cellForRowAt methods are in the same class

-> I have even assigned the object of the same class to the dataSource & delegate property

So my problem is the numberOfRowsInSection is getting called but the cellForRowAt is not getting called. I am just getting a tableView without any cell.

-> I have checked that the numberOfRowsInSection is not returning 0

Please Check The Code Below:

This is the class that I have created. I am creating the object of this class in a UIViewController child class

NOTE:-

1) I have called the configureTV() function in the init method.
In this configureTV() I have assigned both the dataSource & delegate property its value.

2) I have verified that the configureTV() method is getting called

3) I have verified that I am registering the reuseId for the cell

4) I have checked that the dataSource property is being assigned the reference or the object of the class successfully

5) I have verified that the numberOfRows & numberOfSection methods are being called. Even I have tried these two methods with hardcoded values as well

```
import UIKit

class MyClass:NSObject,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
{


    var superView:UIView!

    var tableView:UITableView = UITableView()

    let value = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(superView:UIView)
    {

        self.init()
        self.superView = superView
        self.configureTV()
        print("SuperView Initialized")
    }




    func configureTV()
    {
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self


        self.tableView.frame = self.superView.frame
        self.superView.addSubview(self.tableView)

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {

        print(value.count)
        return value.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath)



        cell.backgroundColor = .green

        cell.textLabel?.text = value[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }



}






//-------Creating The Object Of The Above Class------------



class ABCD:UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {


        let obj = MyClass(superView: self.view)

    }





}
```

----------------------------I Got The Solution-------------------------

I found the solution by myself but the solution is very strange.

Inside the class ABCD I have created an object as Shown below

//Code Before Being Corrected: —

```
class ABCD:UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {


        let obj = MyClass(superView: self.view)

    }

}
```

Now I have done a very minor change i.e. I have made the “obj” variable as the property of the class & the 
Problem got solved.

//Code After Correction Which Solved The Problem:—

```
class ABCD:UIViewController
{
    var obj:MyClass!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {


        obj = MyClass(superView: self.view)

    }





}
```

I want to know why this happened.

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you add your tableview to any view - hence it won't ask for cells...

Comment: In the function configureTV() in the last line I have added the tableView to the superView & I have got the superview object in the init. i.e. self.superView.addSubview(self.tableView)